# What is the regular expression to match the empty string for a rewrite rule?

Tags: regex, url, iis-7, url-rewriting

I need a regular expression for a rewrite rule on iis7, I'm trying to redirect
http://www.website.com to http://www.website.com/sample.  But I only want the empty url string (extra points if you can figure it out with and without '/'), and I'm unsure how to create a rewrite rule to match to that.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
^/?$
```

I think...

Comment: Well, with proper escaping it's: `^\/?$`

Comment: @Anders Why escape forward slashes?

Answer (score 1):

not exactly sure what your looking for but this matches an empty url strip:

http//\Z

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very clear, but I think you want this:

> `^http://www.website.com/?$`

The `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string.
The `/?` optionally matches a trailing slash.