# IIS Rewrite - Redirecting only the root of one hostname to HTTPS?

Tags: redirect, iis, https

I'm trying to redirect only user who enters http ://site.domain.com to https ://site.domain.com

Any other http page should not redirect to https (ex: http://site.domain.com/page2)

I have tried this approach:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site\.domain\.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://site.domain.com/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Or this one:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site\.domain\.com$" />
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://site.domain.com/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

But no redirect occurs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

[What is the regular expression to match the empty string for a rewrite rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473632/what-is-the-regular-expression-to-match-the-empty-string-for-a-rewrite-rule)

But I would try to stick with ^$ and try this variant:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="^$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```